# Are there any instances of significant progress deriving from mathematical 'silliness'?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

Last night I thought I'd be silly finding the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ with real components.  Instead of calculating $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ I tried to compute the determinant by subtracting $\lambda$ in silly ways.

For example I computed

$$\begin{align} det \left(\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{bmatrix}-\lambda \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix} \right)&=0 \\ ad-(c-\lambda)(b-\lambda)&=0  \\ ad-(bc-b\lambda-c\lambda+\lambda^2)&=0 \\ ad-bc+b\lambda+c\lambda-\lambda^2&=0 \\ \lambda^2-\det(A)+\lambda(b+c)&=0 \end{align}$$

Firstly is there a name for $b+c$? I know that $tr(A)=a+d$

Secondly, are there any good examples of interesting maths having been derived from 'silliness'?  I appreciate that "silly" is hard to define but I am referring to a whimsical or carefree maths with no real hope of anything arising from it.  I would be especially interested to hear about mathematics that has been done deliberately incorrectly and yet new ideas are formed or questions arise (in the sense of my example)

**edit**
To attempt a clarification.  My silliness led to me wanting to know about the 'trace' of $b+c$ a question I had not set out to investigate.  I understand the question is vague and so might need closing on that grounds.

I hope this is an interesting question for the community but I shall not hasten to remove it should it not fit site standards.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [Conway's look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) comes to mind but I'm not sure if it is silly in the same sense that you mean.

Comment: To downvoter: I will remove the question if it falls short of site standards. If there is a remedy to a specific concern I will gladly make it.

Comment: $64/16 = 4$ because you can cancel the $6$'s.

Comment: Not downvoter but I think it would help to narrow the question.  Lots of mathematics has its origins in doing things deliberately incorrectly, like subtracting a larger number from a smaller one, or taking the square root of a negative number.

Comment: @DanBrumleve that's a good example, I'd forgotten about.

Comment: $\frac{\sin x}{n} = six = 6$.

Comment: @DanBrumleve it's a fair point but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Much of theoretical physics is silly in the sense of your question. Has theoretical physics produced meaningful mathematical progress despite questionable foundations? The answer is clearly yes. Our knowledge of the topology of $4$-manifolds is largely due to what was first wild conjecture (guided by physical intuition). This story is ongoing.

Comment: Kronecker thought set theory was silliness, but it certainly is a significant progress. Silliness lies in the eyes of the reader :-) I agree with Dan's metacomment on your post, and he also illustrates the phenomenon: while these advances were certainly not silly (you have to take care to define a consistent system), some dogmatists views rejected these silly mental exercises (God made integers, man made the rest).

Comment: If you formulated your question as "have some significant mathematical progresses been considered silly", then the answer would be "most of them", with many striking examples, such as Gauss afraid that philistines would not forgive him if he introduced noneuclidian geometry.

Comment: Pancake sorting comes to mind as a bit of mathematical silliness that turned out to have more depth as people looked into it, and some application in computer science.  Bill Gates wrote a paper on pancake sorting, the only academic paper he ever published.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Dan Brumleve in the comments, I was immediately reminded of John Conway, in particular of [this article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20150828-john-conway-a-life-in-games/) which you may find of interest. Its introduction reads:

> John Horton Conway claims to have never worked a day in his life. This adaptation from the biography *Genius at Play* shows how serious advances such as the surreal numbers can spring out of fun and games.

... although upon consulting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number), it seems the surreals were not entirely unknown before.

Comment: Just read the article.  I'd heard of life before but not traffic game. Thanks.